# Create a year/quarter table in SQL without a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a start year and an end year, say 2017 and 2019 for example.

I'd like to create a table with columns *year* and *quarter* (eg, 1, 2, 3, 4) between my stated startYear and endYear, and have *quarter* for the final, *endYear*, to stop at 2 (it's always forward looking).

Sample desired output below.

```
year    quarter
2017    1
2017    2
2017    3
2017    4
2018    1
2018    2
2018    3
2018    4
2019    1
2019    2
```

Seems like it should be simple, nothing occurs to me except somewhat clunky methods relying on a loop or UNION or simply inserting values manually into the table.

Comment: Why does quarter always stop after 2 in the final year?

Comment: the final year is meant as a forward looking buffer...always [year run] + 1, 2 quarters is enough.

Comment: Since I'm sure your use case will be expanded, why not just do this **once** into a persisted table so you never have to calculate anything again. Aaron Bertrand has a great script for this [check it out here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) and it's super fast

Comment: @scsimon, just used once within a broader SP.  +1 for the link though

Comment: That's fair @Chris but it's just used once until you need it again lol. Keep that handy, it'll come back around when you want the first of the month, week of the month, and all the other random calculations that slow down otherwise sargable queries. Cheers!

Comment: If it is just 2-3 years you can always type them.

Comment: Seems like a simple cross join to me, maybe with a WHERE clause if you really need to prevent 2019 Q3&4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just another option... an ad-hoc tally table in concert with  a `Cross Join`

**Example**

```
Declare @Y1 int = 2017
Declare @Y2 int = 2019

Select *
 From ( Select Top (@Y2-@Y1+1) Year=@Y1-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1 ) A
 Cross Join (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) B([Quarter])
```

**Returns**

```
Year    Quarter
2017    1
2017    2
2017    3
2017    4
2018    1
2018    2
2018    3
2018    4
2019    1
2019    2
2019    3
2019    4
```

Comment: Better since on the back end a recursive CTE might as well be considered a loop.

Comment: interesting...appears you're creating a temporary table of sorts for the quarters.  if I'm understanding, 'B' is the alias, and 'Quarter' the column name...can you link to documentation for how a 'table' like this is created?

Comment: @Chris, You can try this `SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3))t(x)` and read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). John, +1 from my side

Answer (score 2):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
with yq as (
      select 2017 as yyyy, 1 as qq
      union all
      select (case when qq = 4 then yyyy + 1 else yyyy end), 
              (case when qq = 4 then 1 else qq + 1 end)
      from yq
      where yyyy < 2019 or yyyy = 2019 and qq < 2
     )
select *
from yq;
```

If the table will have more than 100 rows, you will also need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=57346221f41af37f3508b10f5769b5a6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Shoudn't we write the where condition as -- where yyyy < 2019 or (yyyy = 2019 and qq < 2). Also, in place of qq<2, would it be correct to write <3?

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur . . . First, did you see the db<>fiddle.  The code works.  Second, you can use parentheses.  They are not needed for this logic.  Third, `qq < 2` is correct.  That will end with the value 2.

Comment: My bad! Should have checked db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is very similar to the one by John, but it doesn't depend on a system table.

```
Declare @Y1 int = 2017;
Declare @Y2 int = 2019;

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteYears([Year]) AS(
    SELECT TOP (@Y2-@Y1+1)
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + @Y1 - 1 AS [Year]
    FROM E4
)
SELECT [Year], [Quarter]
FROM cteYears
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) Q([Quarter]);
```

Comment: Hey Luis. Good to see another of the good guys around here. :)

Comment: Just to be clear.  Any table of adequate size will do,   Notice that the Order By

Answer (score 0):

Let me to propose a recursve query for you:

```
WITH prepare AS
(
SELECT tbl.year
FROM (VALUES (2017) ) AS tbl(year)    -- for example, start year is 2k17

UNION ALL

SELECT year + 1
FROM prepare
WHERE year < 2030                     -- and last year is 2030
)
SELECT
    year, quarter
FROM prepare
CROSS JOIN ( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4) ) AS tbl (quarter)
```